# Upgrading ubuntu with some thing which can make more than one connection

Tags: upgrade, internet, wget

I wanna upgrade my Ubuntu from 11.04 to 12.04,but the internet is so slow when I use Synaptic or Update Manager,because they only make one connection to download packages like wget.( 6 ~ 7kbps ).

but when I use axel to download my speed is 160 kbps.

now I'm upgrading and it take 6days to be compelet by this speed.

is there any way to force it to use more than one connection to get packages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is, using a program that is called apt-fast, How to from this site http://www.webupd8.org/2010/08/you-can-now-install-apt-fast-from-ppa.html

First run theses commands in terminal, put one line in at a time and hit enter, enter password when prompted.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tldm217/tahutek.net
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-fast
```

After it is installed you can use `apt-fast` just like `apt-get` aka `sudo apt-fast upgrade`

They say it is a full syntax replacement, so try it with any situation you would use apt-get I haven't had it fail yet, but if something does go wrong try `apt-fast clean` , by default it has like 4 connections, I read here that you can customize it for more here http://nvarona.blogspot.com/2011/01/accelerating-ubuntu-apt-get.html

Comment: Good call.  I didn't know about that one.  +1

Answer (score 1):

I would go around the problem and use some download manager to download the 12.04 ISO with as many threads as you want or use apt-mirror to pull in a repo to a local mirror.

The latter is probably a better option.

Then you could use the local mirror or ISO as your upgrade repository.