# Is there way to Accelerate Package Downloads in slow connections?

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, synaptic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upgrading ubuntu with some thing which can make more than one connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140010/upgrading-ubuntu-with-some-thing-which-can-make-more-than-one-connection)

I'm using **Ubuntu 11.10** and I want to download all (for a specified installation) packages **simultaneously** and in **chunks (as in `jDownloader`)** for **faster downloading** speed. I wanted this because my shared internet connection has no internet load balancing mechanism. I'm using my closest mirror `mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu` (Sri Lanka).

I've used `Ubuntu Software Center`, `Synaptic Package Manager`, `apt-get` and some other package managers to download packages. All of them are using a single connection for all packages which causes slow download (in my connection).

Is it possible to **or** is there a way to,

---

- install an application to handle package downloads of any Package Manager (even in `Update Manager`) in simultaneous connections

---

- find a Package Manager specifically designed for slow connections (uses simultaneous connections in downloads)

---

- if above are impossible

  1. get a list of required packages' URLs
  2. manually download (using a Download Accelerator)
  3. move `*.deb` to `/var/cache/apt/archives`
  4. install packages

---

Please tell if you have a better way

I'm not expert with source code modifying and compiling. So please do not give that kind of answers

I just want to know what is possible and what is the procedure.

Comment: This might help http://askubuntu.com/questions/140010/upgrading-ubuntu-with-some-thing-which-can-make-more-than-one-connection/140016#140016

Comment: You can also have Ubuntu select the fastest download server for you in `Sofware Center -> Edit -> Software Sources... -> Dowload from: -> Other -> Select best Server`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try Apt-fast.

Apt-fast is a shellscript wrapper for apt-get that improves one's apt-get download speed by simultaneously downloading packages with multiple connections per package.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apt-fast/stable -y && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install axel apt-fast
```

After setting it up, you can use it, just like apt-get

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Will be:

```
sudo apt-fast update

sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Will be:

```
sudo apt-fast install chromium-browser
```

Comment: Why is there `axel` in the `sudo apt-get install` command?

Comment: Axel is the download manager, you can also use aria2. But i believe axel is better

Comment: Why is there axel. You didn't mention anything regarding axel

Comment: Like i said, axel is the download manager apt-fast uses. Apt-fast is just a script that uses a download manager like axel or aria2, so it can use multiple connections, if you have doubts please read https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast

Comment: I've edited the commands. Notice that, `apt-get` requires `sudo` in Ubuntu

Comment: Only if you run apt-get as normal user and not root. But yes, i've should have mentioned the need for sudo or run as root. Thanks for the edit

Comment: We must assume the bottleneck is at the OP's end, so multiple download connections will not speed up anything. When this technique does speed up downloads it is at the cost of making other users' connections slower which is an antisocial thing to do imo.  see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/52243/what-is-apt-fast-and-should-i-use-it

Comment: @LnxSlck **This worked perfectly**. I can also update and upgrade packages with acceleration (8 connections).
At first the speed **was 20-50 KB/s** & **now it is 500-900 KB/s** (I think the internet **connection is 8 Mbps**) The `jDownloader` downloads nearly the same speed (8 connections).

Comment: @StephenMyall assume nothing. All you can do in inform the user about possible pitfalls of using the program, or the implications of misusing the program.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can generate a package download script and then download those packages using a download manager.

1. Generate a download script

   For example: If you want to install package `eclipse`, use this command to generate a package download list in a file `download-list`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated -y  --print-uris eclipse | grep http | cut -d \' -f2 > download-list
   ```

   Replace the name `eclipse` with your desired package. If your mirror is an ftp mirror, replace `http` with `ftp`.
2. Then install a download manager. I'd recommend to install `aria2`

   install command: `sudo apt-get install aria2`
3. Download all files

   Create a folder in your home, Name it, *packages*. Copy the `download-list` file in that folder. Then open a terminal by pressing `Ctrl-Alt-T`. Go the the *packages* folder by the command, `cd packages`. Then do this command to download all files:

   ```
    aria2 -i download-list
   ```

   It will download all files in that folder
4. Setup local repo

   Then in the same *packages* folder, Do this command and wait until it finished.

   ```
   apt-ftparchive packages . > Packages
   ```

   Then open `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with command: `gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

   At the top of the file, write this line:

   ```
   deb file:/home/your-user-name-here/packages /
   ```

   Save the file and exit. **remember to replace `your-user-name-here` with your actual login name**
5. Install the package

   To install the package now, use these command:

   `sudo apt-get update` to refresh package database. and then

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated eclipse
   ```

   replace, `eclipse` with actual package name.

For any time to install other package, first generate the download list, download those packages, put them into the *packages* folder and run the command in step 4, and do the commands in step 5.

Comment: I still did not try this method.  BTW, will the local repo causes to stop update (I mean `apt-get upgrade`) the installed package (i.e. `eclipse`)?  Should I have to clean the *packages* folder after the process?

Comment: No, You can generate upgrade package download list also. See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/168352/61218). After downloading the upgrade packages. put them in *packages* folder, regenerate **Packages** file using `apt-ftparchive` command. And No, You never have to delete *packages* folder