# Using apt-fast to download torrents

Tags: bittorrent, apt-fast

While surfing the net I came across a command called `apt-fast` which speeds up downloading packages.

I'm not familiar with this command. Can that command be used to download torrents faster like an album your downloading through a torrent client such as Transmission, and, if so, what do you put at the end of the command to specify what to speed up, eg:do you put apt-fast-(link address) or apt-fast-(eminem discography)? Also, could you run this command in the middle of your download or does it have to be done at the start?

Comment: AFAIK, `apt-fast` is limited to use with apt-get. aria2 does support torrents and you can find extensive details with `man aria2c` if you install aria2. So there's no need to consider `apt-fast`, _per se_, in the context you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Torrents are already fast in this sense, because they download from multiple peers, and start at different parts of the file, downloading in many more pieces then can be achieved with a download accelerator.

apt-fast downloads multiple parts of the file from the same source.

You may be able to use **[Axel](http://axel.alioth.debian.org/)** or **[aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/)** (what apt-fast uses) to download regular files, but not with torrents.

---

If you are asking how to use apt-fast, It is used exactly like apt-get is used to install programs. https://askubuntu.com/a/171562/47291

Comment: ok thanks mateo, thats all i needed to know, i did initially think that it would make very little difference but if it gained even a fraction more of the speed then it would have been useful for a large file for the sake of typing in a command, thanks